# What is a strictly positive probability distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, definition

I'm reading about [Markov Random Fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_random_field). In the wiki page it's written that

> When the joint probability distribution of the random variables is
>   strictly positive,...

I'm so confused! Because a probability distribution gives the probability of the random variable having a specific value and so a probability (per definition) can never be negative! So what do they mean by strictly positive?

Comment: Strictly positive means "positive and never zero". It does not make much sense to take about strictly positive distributions; what is meant is that the probabilities of the "non-trivial" events is non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

At [Markov random field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_random_field) we read:

> > When the joint probability distribution of the random variables is strictly positive, it is also referred to as a Gibbs random field, because, according to the Hammersley–Clifford theorem, it can then be represented by a Gibbs measure for an appropriate (locally defined) energy function.

The words [Hammersley–Clifford theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Markov_random_field&diff=665076558&oldid=660093492) are a clickable link, and there we read about:

> > a probability distribution that has a positive mass or density

If it were to assign positive probability to every event, then it would assign positive probability to every point, and thus it would be a discrete distribution.  Positive density, however means it assigns positive probability to every set whose "measure" is positive.  Every probability density is a density with respect to some *measure*.  For example, consider the density
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1/3 & \text{if }0<x<1, \\  2/3 & \text{if } 1<x<2, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$
The probability that this assigns to the interval $(1.5,2)$ is the measure of that interval, which is $1/2$, i.e. just the length of the interval, *times* the density on that set, which is $2/3$.  More generally, the probability of a subset $A$ is the integral over the set $A$ of the density with respect to the underlying measure.

So it appears that what is intended to be positive rather than zero at that point in that article is the *density*.

I have now edited the article [thus](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Markov_random_field&action=history).

Comment: Just after the Hammersley–Clifford theorem there is a clickable link to [Gibbs measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_measure), which immediately defines $P(X=x).$ It looks discrete to me, although I admit it could just be a case of bad writing in Wikipedia for all I know. (It would be useful if articles about distrbutions would just say explicitly whether they can be discrete, continuous, or mixed, wouldn't it!)

Comment: I suspect that that is just sloppiness. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Could be; but if so, the entire article is equally sloppy. Are all these distributions actually always continuous? It's not my area of expertise.

Comment: @DavidK: It's clear from the context that they are talking about densities, so these are continuous distributions.  For a continuous random variable, it's a somewhat common abuse of notation to write "$P(X=x)$" to mean "$f(x)$, where $f$ is the density function for $X$".

Comment: @NateEldredge The context apparently went right over my head. It doesn't help that the only Markov-anything I know is discrete Markov processes, and the chains look tantalizingly similar.

Comment: What is common among _physicists_ is something I'm not altogether fluent in. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: can you please clarify what is the "measure" in that example and what is a "set"? Is there a difference between them? because somehow a set appears to be the same as an interval and a measure. I'm kinda confused.

Comment: The word measure means either a certain kind of function assigning numbers to sets or the number so assigned to a set. The number be $0$ or $+\infty$ (not usually considered a "number") or anything in between.  The most well known example is Lebesgue measure, named after Henri Lebesgue.  The Lebesgue measure of an interval is the length of the interval.  However, intervals are not the only measurable sets. An only slightly more complicated example is a union of intervals, and there may be only finitely many or infinitely many of those.  The measure of the union of non-intersecting intervals...

Comment: ...is the sum of their measures.  Some much more complicated sets than unions of intervals are measurable.  In general, the measure of the union of non-intersecting sets is the sum of their measures.  The union of any finite or countably infinite set of measurable sets is measurable, and the complement of every measurable set is measurable. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So at any rate, what is intended is that the density is positive, and that doesn't rule out isolated points where the density is $0$, since the measure of an isolated point is $0$. "Positive" really means that if you integrate the density over any set of positive measure, you get a postive number.  For example $x\mapsto xe^{-x}$ would count as a positive density on the interval $[0,\infty)$ despite the fact that it is $0$ when $x=0$, because the measure of the set $\{0\}$ is $0.\qquad{}$